# How to pass variable inside single quotation in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I need to fetch number of books issued in a month from current date, that's why I need to run like this:

```
"SELECT * from issued_books where student_id= :s_id and book_name = :b_name and issue_date between :start_date and :end_date"
```

But in between I need to pass `'2019-02-27'` but my variable gives `2019-02-27`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: by concatination

Comment: pls give me an example @treyBake

Comment: did u tried anything?

Comment: With prepared statements you don't need your variables to be enclosed in quotes. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Nick yes i tried but not working

Comment: `$foo = 'I\'m a string with a variable: '. $var`

Comment: @Md.Iqbal well, you need to show us your code and explain exactly how it is not working. I suggest you read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$issue_date = "'".$issue_date."'";

"SELECT * from issued_books where student_id= :s_id and book_name = :b_name and {issue_date} between :start_date and :end_date"
```

Or

```
$var = "2019-43-43";
"fsdafsdf fsd fsd '{$var}'";
```

Or

```
$var = "'2019-43-43'";
"fsdafsdf fsd fsd ".$var;
```

It should be something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$variable = "'2019-02-27'"; // will return '2019-02-27'
```